# Javascript console.log port

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

I'm creating a small app on Electron with node.js and trying to output the port my app is connected to for development purposes.

This is my MySQL connection code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "xxx",
  port: "3306"
});
```

and my output code:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "<span 
style='color:red;'>Not connected - Please contact Administrator</span>";
  }
  return document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "Connected on port " + 
con.port;
});
```

I tried outputting it with con.port but it just says "undefined". What is the correct fix here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I must be missing something, why don't you just do `console.log(con.port)`?

Comment: @Clonkex tried that, just gives me "undefined"

Comment: Show how you tried it. It's easier for us if we know everything you tried. But also, how do you know `con.port` is a thing? Try just doing `console.log(con);` and seeing whether `port` is a property of `con`.

Comment: @zerkms that worked! thank you so much for the quick fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the source code it looks like you should use `con.config.port`.

References:

- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/96fdd0566b654436624e2375c7b6604b1f50f825/index.js#L13
- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/lib/ConnectionConfig.js#L13

Answer (score 2):

The `con.connect` function doesn't actually return anything. It's an asynchronous function that returns nothing, and executions the function as a callback if there was an error, or it connected. To display the connected port, simply build the options object outside, and access that. `con` which is a mysql connection, doesn't have a public port property.

```
var mysqlOptions = {
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "xxx",
  port: "3306"
};

var con = mysql.createConnection(mysqlOptions);
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "<span 
style='color:red;'>Not connected - Please contact Administrator</span>";
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "Connected on port " + 
mysqlOptions.port;
});
```

Also, as @zerkms stated below, you can access the port through the config object which is a property on the mysql connection:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "xxx",
  port: "3306"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "<span 
style='color:red;'>Not connected - Please contact Administrator</span>";
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML = "Connected on port " + 
con.config.port;
});
```